# Extruding from a plane creates a hollow shape

Tags: extrude

I am making a house in Blender with the help of architect sketches. I have done the wall shapes as 2d-planes, and when I extrude them to create the 3D-wall, it creates the wall but with one end hollow or open if you will. Is it suppose to do that, or am I missing something? Now I have to select the edges to close the gap with "Alt F", and I would love to avoid that procedure. Thank you in advance for your answers! 
Best regards Ulf Nilsson
[image]

Comment: Recalculate normals.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Thak you for your help, it worked like a charm! :)